# Run client.setActivity out of client.once('ready' etc. discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to set the status of the bot based on a user message (not in the code below), but I keep getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null

code is below, thanks in advance

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity("your every move", { type: "WATCHING" }) //works
});
function setStatus(game, type){
    client.user.setActivity(game, type)
}

setStatus("your every move", { type: "WATCHING" }) //returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null"

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: The code in your example won't work because the client is not logged in while you are trying to set the status, if this is not all code consider posting all relevant parts

Answer (score -1):

this code should set the activity. Usage would be `+activity watching/playing/listening game`
BTW the setStatus function also works if you have it in a function (if you call that function in `client.` or that function that calls the function is called by `client.`)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cfg = require("./config.json");
const prefix = "+";

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    setStatus("your every move", { type: "WATCHING" })
});

client.on("message", message =>{
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        args = message.content.substr(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        cmd = args[0].toLowerCase();

        if(cmd == "activity"){
            let type = args[1].toUpperCase();
            console.log(type);
            let game = args
            game.splice(0,2);
            setStatus(game.join(" "), { type: type });
        }
    }
});

function setStatus(game, type){
    client.user.setActivity(game, type)
}
client.login(cfg.token);
```

Comment: that doesn't address the error i'm getting -  the error means that it cannot read the property setActivity of null ie. the user param of the client object